didChangeDependencies hook and precachImg method did not work friendly for local assets load
i want to render multiple images in PageView when scrolling vertically
but images are take 4 to 6 sec even drag up to pageView
even visit stack over flow but which i saw the results not sounds good
in my scanrio, When the single and individual img case its work fine and did not
take time for load and also in drag up again
please help me to resolving
List<String> imagesPaths = [
    'assets/images/darkImg.jpg',
    'assets/images/building.jpg',
    'assets/images/lights.jpg',
    'assets/images/mount.jpg',
    'assets/images/road2.jpg',
  ];
  List<AssetImage> assetImages = [];

  void precacheImages(BuildContext context) {

    for (String imagePath in imagesPaths) {
    
      AssetImage assetImage = AssetImage(imagePath);

      precacheImage(assetImage, context);
      assetImages.add(assetImage);
    }
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    precacheImages(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _isLoading
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : PageView.builder(
              itemCount: quoteList.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                return Stack(
                  children: [
                    Image(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
                      image: assetImages[index],
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                 
                    Container(

                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          getCleanQuote(),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),



       complete code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
// import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:preload_page_view/preload_page_view.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // final AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
  List<String> dataStored = [
    'ali ahmad',
    'noman',
    'shabaz',
    'Ali Akbar',
    'salman rafiq',
    'shabaz',
    'Ali Akbar',
    'salman rafiq'
  ];
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // initAudio();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  List<String> imagesPaths = [
    'assets/images/darkImg.jpg',
    'assets/images/building.jpg',
    'assets/images/leaf.jpg',
    'assets/images/street.jpg',
    'assets/images/road2.jpg',
    'assets/images/leaf.jpg',
    'assets/images/street.jpg',
    'assets/images/road2.jpg',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('example'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: PreloadPageView.builder(
        preloadPagesCount: dataStored.length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: dataStored.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Image(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                image: AssetImage(imagesPaths[index]),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    dataStored[index],
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.63,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('clicked');
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.comment, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
        controller: PreloadPageController(initialPage: 1),
        onPageChanged: (newIndex) async {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
[![error image][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/lO8d1.png




Use this package preload_page_view: ^0.2.0 this will do same task ,just tell how many pages you want to preload to it. This will prevent loadind all images at one time and lessen the burden on main thread and preload the images as you swipe. Even in you do not want to use this package then use preCache images on pageChange and load next 2 images only, but this will increase your work, so just use the above package.
Below is sample code for package
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new PreloadPageView.builder(
     itemCount: quoteList.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemBuilder: ...,
      onPageChanged: (int position) {...},
      .....
      preloadPagesCount: 3,
    );
  }

This will load 3 next pages for you. Meaning total of 4 pages

This error has appear:
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞══
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
'dart:ui/math.dart': Failed assertion: line 14 pos 10: '': is not true.

body: PreloadPageView.builder(
preloadPagesCount: dataStored.length,
    itemCount: 12,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Stack(
        children: [
          Image(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
            image: AssetImage(imagesPaths[index]),  // direct img paths
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
    controller: PreloadPageController(initialPage: 1),
    onPageChanged: (newIndex) async {


can you please give the updated code. Also edit your question and add it there. giving code in comment has many limitation. So edit your question and add it there. Also add the complete error.
